# How to use All() function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

My Method is as follows

```
IEnumerable<T> All(Func<T, bool> filter);
```

How to use Filter parameter in our function?

Comment: But `All()` returns `bool`, [doesn't it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)? Don't use mix with [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a model of:

```
    class Person {

        public property Name {get; set;}
    }
```

and a collection like:

```
    List<Person> personRepo;
```

you can filter your list like:

```
    var searchResults = personRepo.All(p => p.Name == "Frank Borland")
```

Answer (score 1):

its like

```
listitems.All(l=> l.value == data);
```

i.e. its lambda expression that will passed as prameter

**Note** : here listitem is collection ...which is created from class which impelemented IEnumerable i.e. its list, array, others you can check on msdn

Comment: While implementing method how to use T by using filter

Comment: @Muralikrishna -  listcollection with any boolean condition that will work here you can also check below answer that will give you more idea or just read about lambda expression also give you more idea..

Comment: Thanks for your response now i got the solution

Comment: @Muralikrishna - welcome dont forget to accept answer which give your proper infomation that you want...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx), you can see that filter should be a function that takes one parameter of type `T` and returns a `bool`.

So I would think that the `All` method applies the `filter` function to all the elements of a collection, and returns those for which `filter` returned `true`, or something along those lines.

Another option would be a method that tests a collection against a filter and returns true only if all of the items match the filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Func<int, bool> func = i => i > 0; // makes sure all numbers are greater than 0
bool b = arr.All(func); // returns true
```